# Display a hierarchical data table into php codeigniter menu tree view

Tags: php, codeigniter, treeview, hierarchical-data

I created a tree-view data table as below:

```
id | parent_id | name
1     null       Japan
2     1          Tokyo
3     2          Nerima
4     2          Chiyoda
5     null       America
6     5          New York
7     5          Washington
```

I want to retrieve the data and view it in a tree menu. Here is my html code:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">                                                                                        
     <li class="treeview">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-institution"></i>
              <span>Japan</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li>
                   <a>Tokyo</a>
                   <ul class="treeview-menu">
                      <li><a>Nerima</a></li>
                      <li><a>Chiyoda</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="treeview">
          <a><span>America</span></a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li><a>New York</a></li>  
              <li><a>Washington</a></li>                          
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my query code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM menu_tree WHERE parent_id='".$parent_id."' ORDER BY name";
```

I did some research but couldn't find a way to display the data array into expected menu tree. Is there any solutions I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found out the solution.
Calling this function below will display the expected menu.
For those who face the same problem.

```
function build_menu($rows,$parent)
    {
        $temp = "<ul class=\"treeview-menu\">";
        $result = "";
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            if ($row['parent_id'] == $parent){

                $result.= "<li class=\"treeview\"><a href=" . site_url('admin/dashboard?id=') . $row['id'] ."><span>{$row['name']}</span></a>";
                if ($this->has_children($rows,$row['id']))
                    $result.= $temp . $this->build_menu($rows,$row['id']);                   
            }
        }
        $result.= "</ul>";

        return $result;
    }
    function has_children($rows,$id)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if ($row['parent_id'] == $id)
            return true;            
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is code in view file:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">        
    <?php echo $CI->menu_tree->build_menu($menu_tree,0);?>                                                                                                                          
</ul>
```